# Get the checked status of the checkbox in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

net mvc3 application I have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="daStores" name="CheckBox1" onclick="filter()" />
```

How do I get if its checked or not from the controller?

something like this

```
public ActionResult GoToPage(string page)
{
    bool ischecked = //get the checked status from the view
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely simplistic (and unrealistic) piece of code I'm going to show, but you have to submit the form to the controller.

HTML:

```
<form action="MyController/MyAction" method="POST">
   <input type="checkbox" id="daStores" name="CheckBox1" onclick="filter()" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(bool Checkbox1)
{
    bool ischecked = Checkbox1;
}
```

Sounds like you have a very poor understanding of how ASP.NET MVC works, I think you should try working with some introductory tutorials before jumping right in.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Can't this be done without submiting a form? I have a link that loads a partialview via an action in the controller. and I want to load different partial views depending on the checkbox status. thanks

Comment: Controllers reside on the server and are only accessible via HTTP requests (GET, POST, etc).  Your partial view is doing this without you realizing it.  I'm not trying to sound like a jerk but you really need to learn the basics of MVC.

Comment: ok I got it. Thanks for the tips. Sorry about the stupid questions but personnaly I prefer to learn programming by trying, asking and exploring codes. I think if you explore you can learn a lot better than reading long documents.

Comment: I agree, but MVC is complex, so it's better to start with a simple (working) example and manipulate it to see the results rather than go off on a coding frenzy not understanding the basic framework behind what you're working with.

Comment: Use some Jquery get the value of the checkbox before you submit the form. And for god sake use a view model

Comment: @CrazyCoderz none of that is necessary, in fact quite the opposite.

Comment: Are you stating that using a ViewModel is a bad idea? Or overkill with the Jquery?